# sem_open() on macOS success on command line, fail on Application

Tags: multithreading, macos, semaphore

sem_open() posix function success on macOS command line test code, but it fails on macOS App test code. It returns 0xffff.... and errno=1(EPERM) or 17(EEXIST).
I run same code on command line and app as attaching.
I use Xcode generated capability settings and Info.plist.

Command line code : works

```
//  main.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        sem_unlink("pSem");
        errno = 0;
        sem_t *sem = sem_open ("pSem", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777, 1);
        fprintf (stderr, "sem=%p errno=%d\n\n", sem, errno); // sem=0x03 errno=0
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ViewController.m of application code : fail

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#include <semaphore.h>
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    sem_unlink("pSem2");
    errno = 0;
    sem_t *sem = sem_open ("pSem2", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777, 1);
    fprintf (stderr, "sem=%p errno=%d\n\n", sem, errno); //sem=0xff...ff errno=1 or 17 
}
@end
```

I use macOS Big Sur 11.2.3, Xcode 12.4

Comment: If I change myapp.entitlements App Sandbox=NO, this code worked.

Comment: I use dispatch_semaphore_create() and it worked with Sandbox=YES

Answer (score 1):

Something is different in the larger environment of your failing case.

When `sem_open` fails, it returns SEM_FAILED — which is probably `(sem_t *)-1` on your system — and the `errno` values will tell you what went wrong:

> EEXIST - the named semaphore already exists, but you asked to exclusively (O_EXCL) create (O_CREAT) a new semaphore by that name.
> EPERM - your process lacks the permissions to open the semaphore.

That latter error code is not documented in OS X man pages that I can find, but some (BSD) systems set that error when owner permissions interfere with the operation.